# including the same DIV in several HTML pages

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, iframe

Below is an image of a HTML page that I need a little advice with.

The large square is an AJAX DIV that gets reloaded when a user changes pages. (works fine).

The smaller black rectangle is a DIV that is including in many of the pages and it has a few different states. I want to keep the current state regardless of which page the user is on and I'm struggling to work out how to include this.

I've been using PHP include but it reloads the code again each time - eg: current state lost.

I was considering using an iframe but I'm not sure if I can iframe to a DIV and then I have the added issue of the red square which pops out from the smaller black rectangle when certain selections are made. Not sure if I could include all this in an iframe when there is other information behind the red square on the page - eg: the iframe needs to overlap other information...

any advice? I can explain more/better if needed.

thx

[image]

Comment: can make AJAX request each state change and store in session or other server storage of choice, or use localStorage with cookie fallback, or url param or hash. Parsing state to change a className at either end wouldn't be difficult

Comment: ok so you idea would be using PHP to include the code as I already an then then a server side storage method like session to advice on the state...

Comment: sure...then in php for the output modify className of the element. AJAX part is simple to put together.

Comment: I have my answer - thankyou... is there a way to close this question? if does it remain open or hope for a comment below to tick?

Comment: Local session storage seems ideal what you're doing; unless you need IE6/7 support....

Answer (score 0):

One of the following might fit your needs:

- localStorage: http://www.joelennon.ie/2011/02/11/basics-of-html5-local-storage/
- PHP Sessions: http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php
- PHP Cookies: http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php

These techniques allows you to simply save data. Say you've named your different states. Save that string in some way, and read it to decide in which state to show that black box.